# How to use groupby/Lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8

```
public class Emp {

    public String name;
    public String department;
    public double salary;

    public Emp(String name, String department, double salary) {

        this.name = name;
        this.department = department;
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

1. So I am trying to get top 5 departments by summing salaries and
2. Also trying to top 5 employees in a department say sales

How do I use groupBy in java 8 and then summing and sorting

This is the data I have

`Emp("Michael", "Sales",20000.0)
 Emp("Jean","Marketing",250000.0)
 Emp("Jason","Biz-dev",220000.0)
 ..........`

Comment: I would imagine you need to write some code.

Comment: your question is ambiguous.

Comment: if I am not mistaken you basically want to group the departments by top salaries and then take the top 5?

Comment: yep how do I do that using java 8

Comment: Any solution other than "use a database" is going to be horribly non-performant. Why is `department` a `String`?

Comment: I know DB would have been very good performance wise but that is what the data is as of now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Top 5 departments by total of salaries:

```
List<String> top5Departments = employees.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.department,
                 Collectors.summingDouble(e -> e.salary)))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue().reversed())
    .limit(5)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Top 5 employees by salary in a specific department:

```
List<Emp> top5SalesEmployees = employees.stream()
    .filter(e -> "sales".equals(e.department))
    .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(e -> e.salary).reversed())
    .limit(5)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought about putting directly into a `Map` that supports order by values. Such a thing does not exist in jdk, but does in `guava` for example. So your solution *could* look like this:

```
 Map<String, Double> map = employees.stream().collect(
            Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Emp::getDepartment,
                    Collectors.summingDouble(Emp::getSalary)),
                    x -> ImmutableMap.<String, Double> builder()
                            .putAll(x)
                            .orderEntriesByValue(Comparator.comparing((Double d) -> d).reversed())
                            .build()));

    map.entrySet().stream().map(Map.Entry::getValue).limit(5).forEach(System.out::println);
```

This is not *better* then the solution already provided, it's just something that *could* be done like this.